# timezone won't set in docker container, django-image, docker version: 4.21.1

Tags: docker, utc, python-datetime

I followed a tutorial on [source](https://tecadmin.net/change-timezone-in-docker-container/), added to my image the following code:
`

1. RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata
2. ENV TZ=Europe/Brussels
3. RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ >
   /etc/timezone

I then rebulit image and in the fresh docker container it seems that the local time is still UTC0 for some reason. I know that, beacuse timing of my project is all logged. If it helps, I use datetime.now().time() to get current time in my project.

Comment: What base image are you using? How to set the timezone can be different depending on your base image. You just need to find the appropriate instructions for whatever base OS you've got.

Comment: I use django image